# "Every" being used instead of "ever"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, adverbs

Occasionally I'll see a comment on the internet along the lines of

> I don't think I have every heard of such a thing.

Maybe not exactly that, but something equivalent where I would think that their use of *every* was 100% wrong, and *ever* should be used instead. It happens way more often than I would think, considering how much extra effort is needed to type the extra *y* and how dissimilar the two words are. Is it because

1. they are simply in the habit of typing "every" every time?
2. they actually have these words confused (how/why)?
3. they are all kids and most English speakers pass through this phase of misunderstanding?
4. they have all learned English as a second language, and either the words are equivalent in their native language, or there is a certain teaching style that doesn't make the distinction clear?
5. of some other reason I've failed to consider?

Comment: All of the above

Comment: not to mention helpful *word anticipating programs* that not only change words from what you typed to what you meant, but also change words from what you typed to what it thought you meant.

Comment: actually, in this case, the 'of' was intentional, so that if you were to take out #s 1-4, the sentence would read "Is it because of some other reason I've failed to consider" :) But yes, I have made this mistake before (although since the f and r are so close, it might be a slightly different process)

Answer (score 4):

Option 1.  This is a common muscle-memory typo.

Comment: Yep. I've definitely typed "every" (and sometimes even absent-mindedly typed out "everyone") when I meant to simply type "ever", simply because of muscle-memory.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that this would be a muscle-memory typo, since only the "y" is typed with the right hand. More likely it's from auto-complete.

Comment: @only_pro Muscle memory isn’t restricted to one hand. We mentally process words as units, and our muscle memory in typing them tends to reflect that. Certain particularly common words become units that we type almost entirely from muscle memory; how often do we type _and_ instead of _an_ or indeed _every_ instead of _ever_ (I do both all the time).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ESL to me, but it could easily be a common typo as mentioned by chaos.